# 「三昧だと」と「帰宅しようとしていた」 meaning?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I can read this sentence for the most part but i can't seem to quite translate it properly or into something that flows naturally.

he's talking from a view of recalling a set of memories.

> 無事にゲームを獲得し、後は家に帰ってゲーム**三昧だと**、上機嫌で**帰宅しようとしていた**、そんな時だった。

Sentence afterwards to give some context：携帯をいじりながら俺の前を歩いていた女の子。

here's what I can currently read/understand/translate it as

"I acquired my game without any problems, after I went home ....missing text i can't translate properly.... in a good mood I went home (i don't understand what this construction does, i have tried to figure it out but can't find anything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 〜[三昧]{ざんまい}: to be absorbed in ~
>
> だと: Here, it means he was thinking about something, an abbreviation of 〜だと思って...
>
> 帰宅: return home
>
> しようとする: to try to do something (often used when the action didn't actually complete)

So, putting this together we get a translation like:

> It was then, on his way home after getting his hands on a new game, when he was thinking cheerfully about all he had left to do was go home and get absorbed in the game.

This is somewhat non-literal and probably could be refined to more slightly more natural, but you get the idea.

Comment: Ah, thank you. i get what it's trying to say now.